Dark Mode On Debian 12 won't update Gnome
I installed Debian 12 on an HP Workstation yesterday and then copied over my home folder and my /var/www folder to the new machine from an ssd. Everything is working fine but for some reason my terminal isn't the black theme. In the top right control thing I set it to dark mode. I also set my terminal in preferences to dark mode, but it is staying on light mode. I really need this to be fixed because it is hard to see the text on the terminal.
Update 1: I didn't use the correct setting it is fixed now.

Gnome termial didn't designed the terminal configuration window so well, the configureation window will always be white no matter what you do.
However, to make the terminal it self to have a dark background and bright text, launch a terminal -> click 3 line button on top right -> click perference -> click first option under "profiles" (most likely called "unamed") -> colors -> change color scheme manually or use pre-configured ones that's avaliable.
